# Bulk Insert Data from List of Dictionaries into Postgresql database [Faster Way]?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

For Example:

```
books = [{'name':'pearson', 'price':60, 'author':'Jesse Pinkman'},{'name':'ah publications', 'price':80, 'author':'Gus Fring'},{'name':'euclidean', 'price':120, 'author':'Skyler White'},{'name':'Nanjial', 'price':260, 'author':'Saul Goodman'}]
```

I need to insert each dictionary into already created table by just taking 'author','price' 
I have like 100k records to be inserted into table. 
Right now what I am doing is to loop through the list of dictionaries and take the required key/value pair and insert one by one

```
def insert_books(self, val):
    cur = self.con.cursor()
    sql = """insert into testtable values {}""".format(val)
    cur.execute(sql)
    self.con.commit()
    cur.close()

for i in books:
    result = i['author'],i['price']
    db_g.insert_books(result)   #db_g is class - connection properties
```

So is there a faster and easier way to bulk insert the data like 10k at a time?

Comment: What's your database? Such performance optimizations tend to be rather database-specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert multiple rows into DB with Python list of Tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058984/insert-multiple-rows-into-db-with-python-list-of-tuples)

Comment: DB: Postgresql.

Comment: Some rationale for that dup target -- you're 1 step away from having a list of tuples, and it will be fewer transactions to do them all at the same time. You should be able to deduce how to do it in one transaction using the info in that post

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks @MoxieBall

Answer (score 1):

i think bulk insert by dumping the whole dataframe will be much faster..[Why Bulk Import is faster than bunch of INSERTs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041143/why-bulk-import-is-faster-than-bunch-of-inserts)

```
import sqlalchemy

def db_conn():
    connection = sqlalchemy.create_engine(//connection string)
    return connection 


books = [{'name':'pearson', 'price':60, 'author':'Jesse Pinkman'},{'name':'ah publications', 'price':80, 'author':'Gus Fring'},{'name':'euclidean', 'price':120, 'author':'Skyler White'},{'name':'Nanjial', 'price':260, 'author':'Saul Goodman'}]

df_to_ingest = pd.DataFrame(books)
df_to_ingest = df_to_ingest([['author', 'price']])

df_to_ingest('tablename', db_conn(), if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Well you could explain this more clearly. Bulk insert is preferable because it reduces the number of queries. I do not think creating a dataframe from dictionary would be helpful. Check this out. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html

Comment: @mad_ hey thanks for pointing that out!! just went through the pd.to_sql, i think there are multiple queries which are still getting executed, but i think this approach is much simpler.. :)